# Pyglet always shows "press 1 to begin" (python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.6, pyglet

I haven't seen anyone else post about this. I've downloaded pyglet for python 3.6, but when I import it and run the program, all I see is "Press 1 to begin". After entering "1", the program generates a random number, repeating the same question over and over.

```
import pyglet

Press 1 to begin.1
4
Press 1 to begin.1
3
Press 1 to begin.1
5
Press 1 to begin.1
6
Press 1 to begin.1
4
Press 1 to begin.1
5
Press 1 to begin.1
4
Press 1 to begin.1
6
Press 1 to begin.1
2
Press 1 to begin.1
7
Press 1 to begin.1
5
Press 1 to begin.1
6
```

Comment: I bet you've got a file called `pyglet.py` in the folder you're running Python from.

Comment: I bet it does something like `while True: input("Press 1 to begin"); print(random.randint(1, 10))`

Comment: @AdamSmith There is no pyglet.py in the same folder as I'm running python from.

Comment: Do `import imp` and then do `imp.find_module("pyglet")` and this will show you what "pyglet" you're importing. *(Later, when this pretty sweet short function call gets rekt by the latest changes to Python, you'll have to do something like: `import importlib.machinery` and then `importlib.machinery.PathFinder().find_module("pyglet").get_filename()`)* This SHOULD give you `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/__init__.py`. If it doesn't, all the above are correct. You've just named your file to "pyglet" some where.

Comment: I failed to mention, you should do this in a python interpreter or in your code before you do `import pyglet` - in order to figure out what "pyglet" actually points towards.